# Wait for program to start

Tags: c#

how could I wait for a program to be started after pressing a button in C#?

I have tried: `foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessByName("process")) { //Then displays something when the program starts }`
But this was not working for me, I am trying to press the button, hide the form with `this.Hide();`. And then when the process has started it will display a message box to notice you that the process is active.

edit: figured it out!

Comment: depends 100% on the process and if it provides and info about it being ready. from your programs point of view, once the process is _started,_ it's started.

Comment: It 100% does provide info when it is running. I am pretty new to .NET and C# in general. But my friend suggested me to while loop until true, but I wasn't sure what that meant.

Comment: then i'd suggest [reading up](https://www.w3schools.com/cs/cs_while_loop.asp). or asking your friend again what he meant - always a good advise.

Comment: Have you tried using mutex object? Process A can spawn process B and wait for a mutex with handle name 'MutextGeneratedByB' with a timeout. If the mutex object is spawned in specified timeout (which you can control using config files and similar mechanisms) and then wait for it in process A.

Comment: Are you starting it yourself?  Then use [Process.WaitForInputIdle()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.waitforinputidle?view=netcore-3.1).